# Através de este código existe alguma maneira de mudar a cor de fundo de cada item da listView

Tags: android

É assim que estou a fazer a listagem gostava de saber se é possível colocar cada item com uma cor diferente por exemplo 1 a branco e outro a preto

```
ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(MainActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, list);


 lista.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Vi este exemplo mas só se adapta se eu tiver uma class adapter , alguma maneira de adaptar isto ao código que mostrei em cima?

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) { 

/* remainder is unchanged */ 

convertView.setBackgroundColor(position % 2 == 0 ? Color.WHITE : Color.GREY); 
return convertView; 
}
```

Comment: Não, terá de implementar um *custom adapter*.

Comment: @ramaral pois é como eu lhe tinha dito...

Answer (score 1):

Para este nível de customização, será necessário implememtar um ArrayAdapter!

Segue um exemplo, esta é uma nova classe:

```
class Adapter extends ArrayAdapter<String>  {

        private final LayoutInflater inflater; 
        public Adapter(Context context, final List<String> list) {
            super(context, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, list);
            this.inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);

        } 
        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
             String item = getItem(position);
            if(convertView == null){
                convertView = inflater.inflate(android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, null);

            }

            TextView.class.cast(convertView.findViewById(android.R.id.text1)).setText(item);
            convertView.setBackgroundColor(position % 2 == 0 ? Color.WHITE : Color.GREY);
            return convertView;
        }
    }
```

Para utilizar, segue:

```
Adapter adapter = new Adapter(MainActivity.this, list);
 lista.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: lista.setAdapter(adapter);  entra onde no seu código ?

Comment: Editei a resposta, espero ter ajudado! Saudações

Comment: tentei usar  o Adapter adapter = new Adapter< String >(MainActivity.this, list);
 lista.setAdapter(adapter); mas deu erro na em "< String  > mais concretamente em String

Comment: tente assim : Adapter adapter = new Adapter(MainActivity.this, list); Desculpe-me!

Comment: Continua  com erro

Comment: a classe é chamada sem o parametro '< String >': Adapter adapter = new Adapter(MainActivity.this, list);